# What edition of odoo is default in odoo.sh

Tags: odoo, odoo.sh

I want to install odoo using odoo.sh, but i need a good reference of prices .what edition of odoo is in odoo.sh by default, if it is a community how to change it to enterprise?

Comment: Odoo sh has Enterprise edition